# Groovy String adding quote to begining of string instead of end

Tags: java, string, grails, groovy

```
public ArrayList<String> findLocationOfXMLDocumentsWithSkills(ArrayList<String> skillsToFind){

    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> fileLocationToNumberOfHits = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>(); 

    def sql = Sql.newInstance(/jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\pdfFileSystem.db/, "org.sqlite.JDBC")
    sql.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS skillList(SKILL TEXT NOT NULL, xmlFile0 TEXT, xmlFile1 TEXT, xmlFile2 TEXT)')

    fileLocationToNumberOfHits.put(1, new ArrayList<String>());

    for(String skill: skillsToFind){

        skill = skill.toUpperCase();
        def query = 'SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL="' + skill + '"'
        println query
        sql.eachRow(query) { row ->

            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So, this is the code I am trying to run using Grails.

For all but the last iteration of the for loop the println query will print
`"ELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL ="{skill}`
where {skill} is replaced with whatever the skill is.

Why is it replacing the first character of the string with a `"` instead of adding it to the end of the string?

I have this same piece of code being run in other functions in this same class and it works
exactly as it should.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What's the content of 'skillsToFind' ?

Comment: Why not use `sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL=$skill") {` so you aren't opening yourself up to sql injection?

Comment: skillsToFind is an ArrayList of Strings created from a textArea on my site with the skills listed on individual lines. I split on '\n' to create the List. I then pass it to this function.

Comment: I tried sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL=$skill") and def query = "SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL='$skill'" but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: So, I tried adding a newline after the last skill listed and the problem then occurred for the last iteration as well. So I think it is a problem with the formation of the skillsToFind list formation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with the split function I used to generate skillsToFind.

I used .split('\n') on a String generated from a textArea on my site. 
The resultant strings had an extra character of some kind at the end of the string (except for the last one since it wasn't split on).

I just removed that character from the string and now everything is working.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
def query = 'SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL="' + skill + '"'
```

for:

```
def query = "SELECT * FROM skillList WHERE SKILL='$skill'"
```

More info about Strings and GStrings in groovy:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString